# how to set Visual Studio CMake project run time environment variable?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, dll, visual-studio-2022

## Visual Studio 2022 CMake project

I build a qt cmake project in vs2022, everything works well, but when last step to run exe, it says the error of lack of dll files. I know that this is the problem of dll file directory. I can add it to system env path, or copy dll to exe file dir, but I guess that additional way that **not mucks system env** exists. I notice that **VS traditional project** can set debugger env in property, which set a local env variable, but I cannot find the way to set this in new support **CMake Project** in VS2022.

The IDE QtCreator also provide an analogous way that set env var for only project to run exe file, so any way to set this in VS like the **traditional sln project**, I search and find that some configure json file may help, but I cann't find precise setting.

As above, I guess some ways exist to **set exe runtime env var** to find dll file in **VS CMake project**, anyone could give me any tip, any helpful advice would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The dlls typically differ by subsystem (x86 or x64) and compiler options, also you need to copy those together anyway if you want to deploy the binaries (or make installer).

Comment: When dealing with Qt, I always just add to the path on my dev machine, it's a lot simpler. The other thing you can do, and I do this with postgres libraries, is copy the relevant files as part of a post build step to the output directory.

Comment: When I deploy the project, I will use qtdeploy to copy dll file, but I want just run exe without additional dll copy while debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found the way for cmake project without solutions in visual studio,

1. find `launch.vs.json` file by [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/launch-vs-schema-reference-cpp?view=msvc-170)
2. add custom env variable path to json file
3. add following content to project in `configurations` key:

```json
 "env": {
    "PATH": "<dll-file-path>"
 }
```

It works well for me, hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following properties to your `CMakeLists.txt` file that contains the executable target:

```
set_property(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT <your_executable_target_name>)
set_property(TARGET <your_executable_target_name> PROPERTY VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT "PATH=${QTDIR}/bin")
```

Comment: You probably should do `set_target_properties(executable_target PROPERTIES VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT "PATH=${QTDIR}/bin;$ENV{PATH}")` just in case you need additional dlls that are in the normal `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: According to Visual Studio documentation the debugger environment variable is handled as "merge path" that is merged with the original path.

Comment: Thanks for reply, this works when I choose **cmake -G Visual Studio**, then I open `sln` file, when visual studio load the sln and  open project in a new window, now the question is that I want to run the **CMake project** supported by vs2022 directly without project switch, in addition, if I build cmake -G **Ninja** (this works faster than vs `sln` project), the way that set `VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT`  is not working, so anyway to solve this scene?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a build system independent solution, adding a custom target that simply launches the program could be an option:

**Helper script (run_program.cmake)**

```
set(ENV{PATH} "${PATH}")
execute_process(COMMAND "${PROGRAM}")
```

Actual project

```
add_executable(MyProgram ...)

add_custom_target(RunMyProgram COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D "PROGRAM=$<TARGET_FILE:MyProgram>" -D "PATH=${QT_BINARY_DIR};$ENV{PATH}" -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/run_program.cmake)
```

This allows you to use e.g.

```
cmake --build build_dir --target RunMyProgram --config Release
```

after building to run the program with the modified `PATH` environment variable.

---

Another option would be to use `add_test` + ctest, to run the program with a modifier environment, but this could easily render real test cases unuseable.

Answer (score 0):

In your CMakeSetting.json file, add a key-value under configurations: {"environments":"qt path;$penv{PATH}"}, like this:

```
// CMakeSetting.json

{
    "configurations":[
     {
         "name": "x64-Debug",
         "generator": "Ninja",
         "configurationType": "Debug",
         "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64_x64" ],
         ...
         // run time environments
         "environments": [ { "PATH": "C:\\local\\Qt\\Qt6.5.3\\bin;$penv{PATH}" } ] 
         ...
    ]
}
```